# JSON reading in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using **python 2.7** .I am creating 3 lists (float values (if it matters at all)), i am using json object to save it in a file.
**Say for eg.**

```
L1=[1,2,3,4,5]
L2=[11,22,33,44,55]
L3=[22,33,44,55,66]
b={}
b[1]=L1
b[2]=L2
b[3]=L3
json.dump(b,open("file.txt","w"))
```

I need to read these values back from this "file.txt" into the 3 list.
Can anyone please point me to the resource?
How do i proceed with retrieving these values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730119/retrieving-json-objects-from-a-text-file-using-python

Comment: did you try `content = json.load(open('file.txt'))`?

Comment: http://devdocs.io/python/library/json#json.load

Comment: @TanveerAlam No, i have revised though that post.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
content = json.load(open('file.txt'))
```

or using a the [with context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for) to close the file for you:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    content = json.load(f)
```

Also, read the library's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: Yes, the Documentation really helped.

Answer (score 0):

I used this following code:

```
import json
path=r"file.txt"
for line in open(path):
    obj = json.loads(line)

x=obj['1']
y=obj['2']
z=obj['3']
```

Now, i will have the List *L1 in x*, *L2 in y* and *L3 in z*