# python extracting multiple json file from a single file in pretty format

Tags: python, json

I have multiple json files clubbed together inside a single log file(huge).
Some of the json have got pretty formatting, but most have not.
What is the best way in python to redirect the json to another file with pretty formatting.(Each json file ends with 3 '}' with sometimes newlines and spaces in between).
Eg:-
{ "Sports":{"cricket":{"batsman": "Bradman","bowler":"Warne"}}}

Answer (score 0):

Have not used it myself, but I would try a package like [this one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JSON-log-formatter/0.0.2).

Answer (score 0):

First you should load the file with `json.load`, then use the indent option is `json.dump`.

```
import json
initial = json.load('yourfile.json')
json.dump(initial, 'yourfile.json', indent = 4)
```

you can also use the sort_keys option, which sorts the keys for the json file.

```
json.dump(initial, 'yourfile.json', sort_keys = True, indent = 4)
```

If you have multiple *valid* json files in one big file, you can do this:

```
with open('yourfile.json') as fp:
    file = fp.read()
    file = "[" + file + "]"
initial = json.loads(file)
```

This well work as long as there's commas sparating them.

Comment: The file itself is a log file, which contains hundreds of json files, so I can't use json.load I guess.

Comment: Does it only contain hundreds of json files and nothing else?

Comment: Just to be sure, do you mind posting exactly a portion of the file to your question? It will be nice for the answerers to see what kind of file we're dealing with. Thanks

Comment: {   "track": {
        "track_data": {
            "trackId": "1A11",
            "serial": 727,
            "ZoneInfo": "ABF2227D",
            "Amount": 1490,
            "Area": "ari-152"
        },
        "MiscData": {
            "State": "developing",
            "Type": "Type-1",
            "Issues": "N/A",
            "Indic": "positive"
        }
    }
}

Comment: There are no commas seperating them, but the json files are valid,with the above code it is expecting delimiter.

Comment: The code you posted above is only one json, do you mean you have multiple files like that one after another without commas or anything separating them?

Comment: If the answer is still no, you could try something like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730119/retrieving-json-objects-from-a-text-file-using-python

Comment: It is not allowing me to paste more , yes I have multiple files like that one after another without any delimiter.